# python mongodb $match and $group

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to write a simple query that gives me the user with the most followers that has the timezone brazil and has tweeted 100 or more times:

this is my line :

```
pipeline = [{'$match':{"user.statuses_count":{"$gt":99},"user.time_zone":"Brasilia"}},
            {"$group":{"_id": "$user.followers_count","count" :{"$sum":1}}},
            {"$sort":{"count":-1}} ]
```

I adapted it from a practice problem.

```
This was given as an example for the structure :
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5304e2e3cc9e684aa98bef97"),
    "text" : "First week of school is over :P",
    "in_reply_to_status_id" : null,
    "retweet_count" : null,
    "contributors" : null,
    "created_at" : "Thu Sep 02 18:11:25 +0000 2010",
    "geo" : null,
    "source" : "web",
    "coordinates" : null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name" : null,
    "truncated" : false,
    "entities" : {
        "user_mentions" : [ ],
        "urls" : [ ],
        "hashtags" : [ ]
    },
    "retweeted" : false,
    "place" : null,
    "user" : {
        "friends_count" : 145,
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color" : "E5507E",
        "location" : "Ireland :)",
        "verified" : false,
        "follow_request_sent" : null,
        "favourites_count" : 1,
        "profile_sidebar_border_color" : "CC3366",
        "profile_image_url" : "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1107778717/phpkHoxzmAM_normal.jpg",
        "geo_enabled" : false,
        "created_at" : "Sun May 03 19:51:04 +0000 2009",
        "description" : "",
        "time_zone" : null,
        "url" : null,
        "screen_name" : "Catherinemull",
        "notifications" : null,
        "profile_background_color" : "FF6699",
        "listed_count" : 77,
        "lang" : "en",
        "profile_background_image_url" : "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_background_images/138228501/149174881-8cd806890274b828ed56598091c84e71_4c6fd4d8-full.jpg",
        "statuses_count" : 2475,
        "following" : null,
        "profile_text_color" : "362720",
        "protected" : false,
        "show_all_inline_media" : false,
        "profile_background_tile" : true,
        "name" : "Catherine Mullane",
        "contributors_enabled" : false,
        "profile_link_color" : "B40B43",
        "followers_count" : 169,
        "id" : 37486277,
        "profile_use_background_image" : true,
        "utc_offset" : null
    },
    "favorited" : false,
    "in_reply_to_user_id" : null,
    "id" : NumberLong("22819398300")
}
```

Can anybody spot my mistakes?

Comment: You have missed a comma that should separate the `$group` and `$sort` pipeline stages.

Comment: Fixed it but still getting a totally wrong result :(

Comment: I've updated the answer with the python implementation, would appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a couple of sample documents with the minimum test case. Insert the test documents to a collection in mongoshell:

```
db.collection.insert([
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5304e2e3cc9e684aa98bef97"),
    "user" : {
        "friends_count" : 145,
        "statuses_count" : 457,
        "screen_name" : "Catherinemull",
        "time_zone" : "Brasilia",
        "followers_count" : 169,
        "id" : 37486277
    },
    "id" : NumberLong(22819398300)
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fd2490bac3fa1975477702"),
    "user" : {
        "friends_count" : 145,
        "statuses_count" : 12334,
        "time_zone" : "Brasilia",
        "screen_name" : "marble",
        "followers_count" : 2597,
        "id" : 37486278
    },
    "id" : NumberLong(22819398301)
}])
```

For you to get the user with the most followers that is in the timezone `"Brasilia"` and has tweeted `100` or more times, this pipeline achieves the desired result but doesn't use the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "user.statuses_count": {
                "$gt":99 
            }, 
            "user.time_zone": "Brasilia"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {                
            "followers": "$user.followers_count",
            "screen_name": "$user.screen_name",
            "tweets": "$user.statuses_count"
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": { 
            "followers": -1 
        }
    },
    {"$limit" : 1}
]
```

**Pymongo Output**:

```
{u'ok': 1.0,
 u'result': [{u'_id': ObjectId('52fd2490bac3fa1975477702'),
              u'followers': 2597,
              u'screen_name': u'marble',
              u'tweets': 12334}]}
```

The following aggregation pipeline will will also give you the desired result. In the pipeline, the first stage is the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator which filters those documents where the user has got the `timezone` field value `"Brasilia"` and has a tweet count (represented by the `statuses_count`) greater than or equal to 100 matched via the [**`$gte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/#exp._S_gte) comparison operator.

The second pipeline stage has the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator which groups the filtered documents by the specified identifier expression which is the **`$user.id`** field and applies the accumulator expression [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max) to each group on the **`$user.followers_count`** field to get the greatest number of followers for each user. The system variable [**`$$ROOT`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables) which references the root document, i.e. the top-level document, currently being processed in the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) aggregation pipeline stage, is added to an extra array field for use later on. This is achieved by using the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) array operator.

The next pipeline stage [**`$unwinds`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) to output a document for each element in the `data` array for processing in the next step.

The following pipeline step, [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project), then transforms each document in the stream, by adding new fields which have values from the previous stream.

The last two pipeline stages [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) and [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit) reorders the document stream by the specified sort key `followers` and returns one document which contains the user with the highest number of followers.

You final aggregation pipeline thus should look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': { 
            "user.statuses_count": { "$gte": 100 },
            "user.time_zone": "Brasilia"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user.id",
            "max_followers": { "$max": "$user.followers_count" },
            "data": { "$addToSet": "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$data"
    },   
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$data._id",
            "followers": "$max_followers",
            "screen_name": "$data.user.screen_name",
            "tweets": "$data.user.statuses_count"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$sort": { "followers": -1 }
    },
    {
        "$limit" : 1
    }
])
```

Executing this in Robomongo gives you the result

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52fd2490bac3fa1975477702"),
            "followers" : 2597,
            "screen_name" : "marble",
            "tweets" : 12334
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

In python, the implementation should be essentially the same:

```
>>> pipeline = [
...     {"$match": {"user.statuses_count": {"$gte":100 }, "user.time_zone": "Brasilia"}},
...     {"$group": {"_id": "$user.id","max_followers": { "$max": "$user.followers_count" },"data": { "$addToSet": "$$ROO
T" }}},
...     {"$unwind": "$data"},
...     {"$project": {"_id": "$data._id","followers": "$max_followers","screen_name": "$data.user.screen_name","tweets":
 "$data.user.statuses_count"}},
...     {"$sort": { "followers": -1 }},
...     {"$limit" : 1}
... ]
>>>
>>> for doc in collection.aggregate(pipeline):
...     print(doc)
...
{u'tweets': 12334.0, u'_id': ObjectId('52fd2490bac3fa1975477702'), u'followers': 2597.0, u'screen_name': u'marble'}
>>>
```

where

```
pipeline = [
    {"$match": {"user.statuses_count": {"$gte":100 }, "user.time_zone": "Brasilia"}},
    {"$group": {"_id": "$user.id","max_followers": { "$max": "$user.followers_count" },"data": { "$addToSet": "$$ROOT" }}},
    {"$unwind": "$data"},   
    {"$project": {"_id": "$data._id","followers": "$max_followers","screen_name": "$data.user.screen_name","tweets": "$data.user.statuses_count"}}, 
    {"$sort": { "followers": -1 }},
    {"$limit" : 1}
]
```